# StackOverflow on save entity with bidirectional ManyToMany attributes

Tags: spring-boot, rest, elasticsearch, spring-data-elasticsearch

Good, I am creating a rest api with spring and elastic, but I have a technical problem during its construction, it turns out that I need to save the users who have clicked favorite a company and for this I have ManyToMany lists (so that it hibernates it generates the intermediate table and save the data in the two entities), the system works perfectly in hibernate and saves the relationship correctly in the database, but when I execute I call the save method of the elastic repository it returns a StackOverflow.

If I put a label to make it obvious (at the 2 entities) it works correctly but I need elastic to somehow keep that relationship, I have thought of duplicating code and having 2 lists, one with the model and the other with the ids (the model is saved in the database and the string of id in elastic) but before I duplicate code and do a possible garbage I would like to ask around here!

```
java.lang.StackOverflowError: null
    at java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.get(ConcurrentHashMap.java:936) ~[na:1.8.0_231]
    at org.springframework.data.convert.CustomConversions$TargetTypes.computeIfAbsent(CustomConversions.java:532) ~[spring-data-commons-2.4.5.jar:2.4.5]
    at org.springframework.data.convert.CustomConversions$ConversionTargetsCache.computeIfAbsent(CustomConversions.java:497) ~[spring-data-commons-2.4.5.jar:2.4.5]
    at org.springframework.data.convert.CustomConversions.getCustomWriteTarget(CustomConversions.java:348) ~[spring-data-commons-2.4.5.jar:2.4.5]
    at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.convert.MappingElasticsearchConverter.writeInternal(MappingElasticsearchConverter.java:588) ~[spring-data-elasticsearch-4.2.3.jar:4.2.3]
    at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.convert.MappingElasticsearchConverter.writeCollectionInternal(MappingElasticsearchConverter.java:839) ~[spring-data-elasticsearch-4.2.3.jar:4.2.3]
    at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.convert.MappingElasticsearchConverter.createCollection(MappingElasticsearchConverter.java:753) ~[spring-data-elasticsearch-4.2.3.jar:4.2.3]
    at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.convert.MappingElasticsearchConverter.writeProperty(MappingElasticsearchConverter.java:713) ~[spring-data-elasticsearch-4.2.3.jar:4.2.3]
    at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.convert.MappingElasticsearchConverter.writeProperties(MappingElasticsearchConverter.java:674) ~[spring-data-elasticsearch-4.2.3.jar:4.2.3]
    at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.convert.MappingElasticsearchConverter.writeInternal(MappingElasticsearchConverter.java:633) ~[spring-data-elasticsearch-4.2.3.jar:4.2.3]
    at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.convert.MappingElasticsearchConverter.writeInternal(MappingElasticsearchConverter.java:611) ~[spring-data-elasticsearch-4.2.3.jar:4.2.3]
    at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.convert.MappingElasticsearchConverter.writeCollectionInternal(MappingElasticsearchConverter.java:839) ~[spring-data-elasticsearch-4.2.3.jar:4.2.3]
    at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.convert.MappingElasticsearchConverter.createCollection(MappingElasticsearchConverter.java:753) ~[spring-data-elasticsearch-4.2.3.jar:4.2.3]
    at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.convert.MappingElasticsearchConverter.writeProperty(MappingElasticsearchConverter.java:713) ~[spring-data-elasticsearch-4.2.3.jar:4.2.3]
    at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.convert.MappingElasticsearchConverter.writeProperties(MappingElasticsearchConverter.java:674) ~[spring-data-elasticsearch-4.2.3.jar:4.2.3]
    at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.convert.MappingElasticsearchConverter.writeInternal(MappingElasticsearchConverter.java:633) ~[spring-data-elasticsearch-4.2.3.jar:4.2.3]
    at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.convert.MappingElasticsearchConverter.writeInternal(MappingElasticsearchConverter.java:611) ~[spring-data-elasticsearch-4.2.3.jar:4.2.3]
    at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.convert.MappingElasticsearchConverter.writeCollectionInternal(MappingElasticsearchConverter.java:839) ~[spring-data-elasticsearch-4.2.3.jar:4.2.3]
```

I pass you the two attributes of the models

Class Business

```
@Builder.Default
@ManyToMany(mappedBy = "commercesFav", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, targetEntity = UserImpl.class)
private List<User> usersFav = new ArrayList<>();
```

Class User

```
@Builder.Default
@ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, targetEntity = CommerceImpl.class)
@JoinTable(name="favorites",
        joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id"),
        inverseJoinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="commerce_id", referencedColumnName="id"))
private List<Commerce> commercesFav = new ArrayList<>();
```

I am using lombok but I think it is irrelevant

By the way, the elastic repositories are basic, empty, they have nothing. I have tried including the Transient tag to some of them, to Commerce and to User but it doesn't work

How can I get elasticsearch to properly save the object?

Thank you!

---

I ended up deleting all lombok from the project, it was impossible for me to debug the code and now the code is more stable and more controlled, if you have the same problem with complex code I recommend deleting libraries like lombok

As much as I try, I have only managed to correctly return the bidirectional lists thanks to JsonManagedReference and JsonBackReference

```
    @ManyToMany(targetEntity = CommerceImpl.class)
    @JsonBackReference
    @JoinTable(name = "favorites",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id", referencedColumnName = "id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "commerce_id", referencedColumnName = "id"))
    @org.springframework.data.annotation.Transient
    private Set<Commerce> commercesFav = new HashSet<>();
```

```
    @ManyToMany(targetEntity = UserImpl.class, mappedBy = "commercesFav")
    @JsonManagedReference
    @org.springframework.data.annotation.Transient
    private Set<User> usersFav = new HashSet<>();
```

From the controller I am saving the 2 models and they are recovered only from the shops (I think that by design it will be better to invert it and that they return from the users)

```
@PostMapping("/commerce/fav/{identifier}")
    public ResponseEntity addFavoriteCommerceToUser(@PathVariable String identifier, @AuthenticationPrincipal UserDetails userDetails, HttpServletRequest request) {
        ResponseEntity<Object> responseEntity = ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND)
                .headers(RequestCustomUtil.getHeader(request)).body(ResponseUtil.beanNotFound(Commerce.class.getName()));

        try {
            Optional<Commerce> commerce = commerceHandle.get(identifier);
            if (commerce.isPresent()) {
                User user = userHandle.findByUsername(userDetails.getUsername());
                Commerce commerceEntity = commerce.get();

                commerceEntity.getUsersFav().add(user);
                user.getCommercesFav().add(commerce.get());
                commerce = commerceHandle.create(commerceEntity);
                userHandle.save(user);

                boolean isActualUser = commerce.get().getUser().getIdentifier().equals(user.getIdentifier());
                responseEntity = ResponseEntity.ok(CommerceBean.CommerceBeanComplete(commerce.get(), isActualUser));
            }
        } catch (CommerceException e) {
            LOG.error(e.getMessage());
        }

        return responseEntity;
    }
```

Comment: Elasticsearch is not a relational database. There is no concept like n-to-m relations between documents in indices in Elasticsearch (this is not specific to Spring Data Elasticsearch).

Answer (score 0):

If you can please add stack trace, that will help understanding which method is getting called recursively.

Although dont have clearcut idea, but sometimes lombok implementations of toString() or equals() can cause the problem. Especially if relation is bidirectional. As a result I add something like below to exclude. Exclude list contains name of properties that holds bidirectional relationship -

```
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = false, exclude = {"emails", "phones", "address", "client", "userRoles"})
@ToString( exclude = {"emails", "phones", "address", "client", "userRoles"})
```